# twentyeleven theme: Where is the code that handles moving the search bar on resize?

Tags: search, menus, custom-header

When twentyeleven theme gets too small, the search bar that was in the nav bar is moved up into the header image. My question is, where is this behavior handled in the theme? I would like to modify it slightly to fit better with my child class.

Comment: Any progress? Was my answer helpful? Do you still miss something?

Answer (score 1):

The search field – `#s` – is floated to the right side, so the following content just moves down when the site is small enough. There are some adjustments to its position in `@media` blocks at the end of the stylesheet. For example this:

```
@media (max-width: 650px) {
    /* other stuff */
    /* Make sure the logo and search form don't collide */
    #branding #searchform {
        top: 1.625em !important;
    }
}
```